# Adding units to an existing front

Tags: civilization-board-game

Can you have more than one unit on a front?

Say A plays a new front with an Archer 3. Then B attacks with an Archer 2. This resolves to B dying, and A surviving with attacking strength 3 and defending strength 1 (3 - 2 wounds).

Is there any way A can now add another Archer 2 to the same front as his wounded Archer 3/1, or MUST he start a new front/attack another unit?

If he can add to the existing front, how would he do this?

Answer (score 2):

When playing units in battle the only choices available are to start a new front, or attack an existing enemy front if there are any - you cannot add more units to an existing front.

From [the rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/support/civilization-rules.pdf) (page 24 under the section **Starting A New Front**):

> There can never be more than one unit in a front.